# How to fix dbghelp.dll error message?

Tags: windows-7, dll

Every once in a while my system just spontaneously pops a message box (5 times in a row) stating:

pcdrsysinfodirect.p5x - Entry Point not found

The procedure entry point SymGetUnwindInfo could not be located in the dynamic link library dbghelp.dll.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkVantage-Technologies/Entry-Point-Not-Found/td-p/444919

```
06-03-2011 04:22 PM
There is a strange interaction between LTT and SQL Server 2005. In some cases,  
LTT tries to access the SQL Server version of a file called DBGHELP.DLL rather  
than the version that is located in C:\Windows\.

We are testing a fix for this problem and expect to release it next month. In  
the  meantime, we have determined a workaround:

1. Navigate to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\
2. Rename DBGHELP.DLL to something like DBGHELP.DL2
```